# Ignoring "print banner page" flag in inbound LPD jobs (CUPS-LPD)

Tags: printing, cups, lpd

I have a USB inkjet printer connected to a server running CentOS 5.7 (64). I installed and enabled cups-lpd so that another Unix server could send print jobs to that printer.

The other Unix server assumes you want a banner page printed unless you use the `-o nobanner` option on it's `lp` command but I have an application there that uses `lp` but has no way to specify that option.

Consequently, the [LPD](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1179.txt) transacion includes a "Print banner page" option (RFC1179 section 7.5) - at least I'm fairly sure (though I haven't checked with tcpdump etc)

The result is I get an unwanted page saying "Cover Page" in big letters and giving Job-Id, Title and User name. This serves no purpose in my environment.

**Is there any way to configure cups-lpd to ignore this "print banner page" flag?**

---

Update: Here's the start of /etc/cups/printers.conf

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.3.7
# Written by cupsd on 2012-09-13 15:43
<Printer inkjet1>
Info HP PSC 2210
Location Ground FLoor, Outlet  A3/A4
DeviceURI usb://HP/PSC%202200%20Series?serial=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
State Idle
StateTime 1347547335
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man cups-lpd`, I discovered you can add

```
  server_args = -o job-sheets=none,none
```

to `/etc/xinetd/cups-lpd` and then ask xinetd to reload it's configuration (`sudo /sbin/service xinetd reload`)

Note: I ran `lpoptions -d printername` to discover this print option <strike>but have not found anywhere it is fully documented (e.g. what each of the two "none"s refer to).</strike>   *The allowed values for this "job-sheets" option are documented at [cups.org](http://www.cups.org/doc-1.1/sum.html#4_2)*

Obviously, this solution applies to all printers rather than a specific printer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/cups/printers.conf` and set the printer's `JobSheets` :

```
JobSheets none none
```

Comment: When I edited `/etc/cups/printers.conf` all the `<Printer printername>` sections already contained `JobSheets none none` - It looks like it isn't obeyed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the contents of the /usr/share/banners to a tar and leaving /usr/share/banners empty.  I did that and now the banners never print.

Comment: -1 for advocating manually messing around in `/usr`. This is almost never a good idea.